# "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 when installing Shapely

Tags: python, pip, shapely

When installing Shapely via PyCharm I got the following Error message:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h4bpp30v\Shapely\
```

and

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install Shapely
Collecting Shapely
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/fb/7a7af9ef7a35d16fa23b127abee272cfc483ca89029b73e92e93cdf36e6b/Shapely-1.6.4.post2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h4bpp30v\Shapely\setup.py", line 80, in <module>
        from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
      File "C:\Users\Anwender\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h4bpp30v\Shapely\shapely\_buildcfg.py", line 200, in <module>
        lgeos = CDLL("geos_c.dll")
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: [WinError 126] Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden
```

I already tried updating pip and setuptools but it still doesn't work.

Does anybody have something else I could try to get it running?

Answer (score 3):

Shapely isn't available through pip. You need to download the Shapely Wheel [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely) and run :
`pip install Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` 
 (depending on the name of the package you decided to download. '37' means python 3.7 version. You can check your python version with `python --version`).